# Exact cost of database round trip vs. wcf service invocation

Tags: database, performance, wcf, caching, orm

I've been googling for exact figures on how expensive round trips are, but could not find any. Are there any concrete numbers given anywhere?

So, we are developing an enterprise solution. We plan to have a thin client connected to a wcf service. In the service we plan to have an ORM (most likely NH) with a 2nd level cache.

Obviously there are numerous benefits to having a service, prominently to encapsulate all the business rules, enable multiple clients to manage concurrency, etc.  But! Performance-wise how does invoking the service from the thin client compare to simply executing raw sql on the client? The service is an added over-head and will surely be slower if the service's orm cache is not hit. Is there some article discussing this in some depth?

Comment: As a quick comment, I would instead be asking for tools to measure performance instead of articles that address your specific use case. There are things like mini profiler (http://miniprofiler.com/) and even Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) that will help you discover how things are performing.

Comment: Fair point, thank you. I guess I can always test this myself, even without the <obviously helpful> tools, I was just hoping somebody might have some prior knowledge about this issue to share.

Comment: In the [words](http://ayende.com/blog/3112/nhibernate-and-the-second-level-cache-tips) of the famous Ayende: “In general, it is more efficient to hit a cache server, because those are very easily scalable to high degrees, and there is no I/O involved.”